# How to create a horizontal list with nativebase

Tags: react-native, listview, native-base

I'm working on mobile application development in react-native as nativebase my frontend library. I'm wondering how can I implement horizontal list item in nativebase

I know I can use FlatList but I'm interested in nativebase list component

Comment: isn't the `List` component deprecated?

Comment: Here I'm using native based list. instead of react-native list component. And its extended from flatlist , so its not deprecated . 
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// import components from native base
import { List, ListItem } from "native-base";

// lets assume your you have this array
let data=[
  {
    pet: 'gsd'
  },
  {
    pet: 'husky'
  },
  {
    pet: 'rotweiler'
  }
];

// inside you render method return this component

return (
   <List horizontal={true} dataArray={data} // your array should go here
         renderRow={pet => (
             <ListItem>
                // if you want you can add a card item here, But I'm adding a simple text
                <Text> {pet.name}
                </Text>
             </ListItem>
         )}>
   </List>

)
```